# TYPO3 Image content element and optionsplit

Tags: image, typo3, typoscript

I try to display couple of images using `image content element` and optionsplit, but every image is rendering only by first `<li>` element - every image has `class="big"`. Is it possible to using option split?

Here is my code:

```
tt_content.image.20.renderMethod = ul
tt_content.image.20.rendering.ul.imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = |
tt_content.image.20.rendering.ul.imageLastRowStdWrap.dataWrap =|
tt_content.image.20.rendering.ul.oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = <li class="big">|</li>|*|<li class="small">|</li>|*|<li class="small">|</li>
tt_content.image.20.rendering.ul.noRowsStdWrap.wrap = <ul class="galleryItems"> | </ul>
tt_content.image.20.rendering.ul.caption.wrap = |
```

Thanks for any help,
Adrian

Comment: try to use doublepipe || instead of |*|

Comment: unfortunately this solution didn't help - still the same name of class

Comment: AFAIR, you need spaces before and after double-pipes (same for |*| ). Maybe, that's the case?

Comment: Not sure right now, but … does dataWrap actually provide optionsplit functionality? Have you tried `oneImageStdWrap.wrap` instead? You don't seem to need dataWrap anyway, since you don't have any variables to parse there.

Answer (score 0):

`dataWrap` is not doesn't provide the optionSplit functionality :
http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/stdWrap#dataWrap

Try to use `stdWrap`.